# how to show that $f$ that satisfy the following must be $\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ complete function, that satisfy $$
f^{\prime}(0)=1, f(0)=0,  \quad f^{\prime \prime}+f=0
$$
Show that it implies that $f= \sin(z)$.

I do not understand what is the difference from the real case, I can just take the derivative and show it satisfies the initial conditions and by the uniqueness theorem, I get the answer.

Comment: Which uniqueness theorem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the one that states that there is only one function satisfy initial conditions

Comment: Well, if you can apply that theorem, then, yes, it's just as in the real case.

Comment: There are many possible ways, depending on which tools you have at your disposal. You can for example consider $g(z) = f(z) - \sin(z)$ and show that its Taylor series is zero.

Comment: I think that you mean that $f$ is an "entire" function.

Comment: @MartinR seems like a tool I can use, but how? I have only information about the first derivative of $f$ and $f$ around $z=0$

Comment: You also have the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is an entire function satisfying
$$
f'(0)=1, f(0)=0,  \quad f''+f=0
$$
then $g(z) = f(z) - \sin(z)$ is also entire, and satisfies
$$
g'(0)=0, g(0)=0,  \quad g''+g=0 \, .
$$
Use this information to show that $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$, and conclude that $g$ is identically zero.

Comment: Is it something weird that $$e^{\dfrac{-1}{x}}$$ also has all derivatives $0$ at $0$ by defining it $0$ at $0$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi: That function is not analytic at $x=0$, and therefore not equal to its Taylor series. In particular it is not an entire function.